# Why shouldn't I leave trees floating in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Sometimes, when I enter a Bedrock Minecraft game and it is loading, a tip shows up:

```
DON’T LEAVE TREES FLOATING!
```

I don't think this does any harm, so why shouldn't I leave a tree floating in Minecraft?

Comment: It's a bad habit, I think. If you leave a piece of wood inside the tree, it still "lives", but players far away may still think it's dying. You should remove all the trunk, in order to make the leaves disappear and maybe spawn saplings.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's either asking Arqader's opinions on whether this is a good idea, which is obviously opinion-based, or is asking why the MCBE developers added this tip, which is a speculative developer intent question.

Comment: @pppery But that's based on potential (right?) answers, which the user doesn't seem aware of. I interpret the question as: will leaving trees floating do harm somehow.

Comment: I _almost_ feel like this is some sort of play on words that was put in as a joke.  "Don't **leave** (as in a leaf of a tree) trees floating" (or *hanging*).  As in the phrase "don't leave me hanging".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know and can tell, it doesn't do any harm; it just might make things a little more difficult and unseemly.

While the tip may have been added more as a joke than a survival strategy, there are several reasons why you wouldn't want to leave floating trees:

- Floating (leaf) blocks can give mobs a place to hide from the sun.
- The leaf blocks also contain resources.
- > Floating trees can cause monsters to spawn in Survival [mode].
  > [source](https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft/discussion/3069988-dont-leave-trees-floating?comment=2)
- > Without the leaf blocks (barring trades) you won't get the saplings to replace the tree that has been taken down.
  > [source](https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft/discussion/3069988-dont-leave-trees-floating?comment=2)
- In multiplayer it's considered a bad habit. I can imagine that is because it ruins immersion. And according to some (many?) players it simply looks [trashy](https://www.quora.com/Why-shouldnt-I-leave-trees-floating-in-Minecraft).
- For whatever reasons they might prefer it as a token of respect to the people running a server.
  [source](https://www.quora.com/Why-shouldnt-I-leave-trees-floating-in-Minecraft/answer/Jay-Mackin-1?ch=15&oid=267468992&share=d14742cf&target_type=answer)